# How to show OrderItem in Order in Django Admin.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show the `orderitemsadmin` in the `orderadmin` using TabularInline but I keep getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'OrderItemAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

This is a Django e-commerce project and I am trying to facilitating the admin viewing the orders and their items.

I think the reason for the error is that I can't set a foreign relation with OrderItem and Order as the sequence is: Orderitem which has a foreign relation with Item, and Order which has a manytomany relation with OrderItem, if the switched their location or sequence it will mess with the ManytoMany relation.

Here is the admin.py

```
class OrderItemAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    list_display = ['item', 'quantity', 'ordered']
    model = OrderItem

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'coupon', 'payment', 'shipping_address', 'status',
                    'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'ref_code']
    inlines = [
        OrderItemAdmin,
    ]
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Here is the models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

Comment: is there admin.site.register() in your admin.py ?

Comment: @sevdimali yes I adjusted the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

**admin.site.register(OrderItem, OrderItemAdmin)**

this line.
An inline can only be used in a modelAdmin that is why you get that error.

Comment: now I am getting `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed`

Comment: It is a different error. This new error is the subject of another question.